# django_celery_results Logs Spill Secrets

Tags: django, celery, django-email

I am using Celery tasks with my Django application.
It has been configured to use `django_celery_results` as a backend for logging task results.

I am however experiencing some issues.

The connection between the broker, Django and Celery is secure. This is no issue.

I am sending mails with celery, I am not storing the credentials on the celery side, nor is it possible to do so as they are provided dynamically.

However, the credentials I pass to the celery task get logged by `django_celery_results`.

These credentials are passed as arguments to my task, IE:

```
send_mail(username=..., password=...)
```

Is there a way to omit these credentials from the task results? I have though about encrypting before sending it to the celery task, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Are you passing the credentials as task arguments, e.g. like so `send_email(..., username="...", password="...").delay()`?

Comment: Yes I am, sorry I'll make it more clear in the question. @BjoernStiel